# How can I make a stored procedure to update one column in one table based on the order of rows from another table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

I have two tables

Users:

```
user    |  name  |  country |  rank              | country_rank       | points
1       |  frank |  US      |  to be determined  | to be determined   | to be determined
```

Awards:

```
awarded_to  |  points_awarded  
1           |  10
1           |  30
```

How can I make a stored procedure to update the users total `points` based off of the `points` from `awards`, then their `rank` and `country_rank` respectively based off of the order of the `points` (i.e. `rank` 1 would be the user with the most `points`)?

I considered making a PHP script and using a crontab to call it occasionally that would just select the info and do the math etc in PHP, but stored procedures seems much more practical for my use-case.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? What have you tried ?

Comment: do a switch based upon column selected.

Comment: Is there no time stamp column in the table Awards? In your example, is the points awarded to user 1, 10? 30? or 10+30? (you don't make the expected result clear)

Comment: @Used_By_Already The amount of points awarded is dependent on the action performed, it could be any amount.

Comment: Thanks for that but please re-read the comment. **Which result** are you **expecting** for your sample? It is your expectation that you have not stated in the question, There was another question too. Is there a timestamp (or any date/time value) in the Awards table?

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table awardsum (user int, total int); #temp
insert into awardsum
select a.awarded_to, sum(a.points_awarded) 
from users u 
inner join awards a on u.user=a.awarded_to
group by a.awarded_to;

update users
join awardsum on users.user=awardsum.user
set users.points = awardsum.total;    

SELECT @row:=0;
UPDATE users
SET rank = (@row:=@row+1)
ORDER BY points desc;

drop table awardsum;
```